# .net core console run as x86 on x64 system

Tags: c#, .net-core

Create via VS2017 preview a .net core 2.0 console app.
Run it, x64, no problem.
Switch properties-> build -> platform to x86
Run it, run hangs and gets nasty message about it not working.
Drop out to command prompt
Navigate to directory where project is
Delete bin and obj
dotnet restore
dotnet run
Get a System.BadImageFormatException.

Any ideas how to build and run this?  Tried installing 32bit framework, no go.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Install x86 DotNET  core run time on your machine. its default location is 
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet

2.update your web.config file

make sure the process path point to x86 version DNC

Answer (score 0):

Install dotnet X86 Runtime from https://dot.net

Comment: you must setup your project condition to works with 32bits
please check this post: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/901#issuecomment-330389374

Comment: This worked for me.  Library I was using from my .net core app was only licensed for x86, not x64.  Removing the x64 runtime and installing the x86 one solved the issue without me having to rebuild or change anything from my end.